# Read file contents and create Map of filename and contents

Tags: scala

I want to read files from given directory then read contents from file and create Map of filename as key and its contetns as value.

I did not got any success but I have tried like this,

```
   def getFileLists(): List[File] = {
      val directory = "./input"
    //  print(new File(directory).listFiles().toList)
      return new File(directory).listFiles().toList
    }

    val contents = getFileLists().map(file => Source.fromFile(file).getLines())
    print(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
getFileLists().map(file => (file.getName, Source.fromFile(file).getLines().toList)).toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is transforming the list of file-names to a list of their contents. You want a `Map[File, List[String]]` instead. To do that the easiest ist to `map` to tuples of files and content, and then call `toMap` on the result:

```
getFileLists().map(file => file -> Source.fromFile(file).getLines().toList).toMap
```

`toMap` works when the input sequence has `Tuple2` as element type. `file -> contents` is such a tuple `(File, List[String])`.

Or in two steps:

```
val xs: Seq[(File, List[String])] = getFileLists().map(file =>
  file -> Source.fromFile(file).getLines().toList)
val m: Map[File, List[String]] = xs.toMap
```

Comment: Thanks, but return type should be Map[File, List[String]] then this code is works , but this is what I want ;). I am new to scala, today i learned implicit conversion from Any to ArrowAssoc. thanks once again

Comment: Oh ok, didn't check for `getLines` types. I correct it now.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your following line

```
val contents = getFileLists().map(file => Source.fromFile(file).getLines())
```

to

```
val contents = getFileLists().map(file => (file.getName, Source.fromFile(file).getLines()))
```

which would give you

```
contents: List[(String, Iterator[String])]
```

Furthermore you can add `.toMap` method call as

```
val contents = getFileLists().map(file => (file.getName, Source.fromFile(file).getLines())).toMap
```

which would give you

```
contents: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Iterator[String]]
```